# Making sure the player and the camera are in the borders

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap

What I need is a way to automatically create an invisible border around the current tilemap (tile map uses simple rectangular tiles)

The player character uses

```cs
rb.movePosition(transform.position + direction * speed
```

and `direction` comes from a custom joystick.

The camera (a pixel perfect camera, as the game is pixel art) is just simply set to be in the same position as the player.

What I want to do is to NOT let the player get out of the map and I don't want the camera to show the black parts around the map (places where nothing is placed), is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Since you said the camera is at the same position as the player, how do you want it to be when the player walks to the border? Should the camera stay put and the player just walks to the border - so that the last tile just touches the border of the screen?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want for my camera

Comment: Is the tilemap fixed or are you generating it dynamically?

Comment: No, it's fixed. But the size of of tilemaps in deferent scenes(levels) differ from each other

Comment: You may want to research unity's Cinemachine. It has "room" like capability that allows you to define an area that limits the camera view inside of it.

Comment: @Nikaas yeah, that seems to have a lot of options though I'm more concerned about keeping player in the map

Comment: Presumably you tried checking whether your new destination position is within bounds before using `MovePosition` to move there? Or clamping the destination to within bounds before moving?

Comment: @DMGregory there is no destination (the character doesn't goes from point A to point B) instead, she just runs in the direction of joystick so I don't think your solution works

Comment: Only adding four 2D box colliders would solve my problem, the thing is I don't know how to get their positions so they would be exactly around the map

Comment: `transform.position + direction * speed` is a destination for where you want to be next frame / next physics step. Don't think so narrowly - it will block you from finding simple answers.

Comment: Ohh yes! I never looked at that as a destination point! And then I can check if that point is on the tilemap or not with a tilemap collider(as trigger)! I'll post this as an answer as soon as I checked it (don't have access to unity right now)